# Windows Already Focused - Ignoring Focus Gain after multiple threads

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I have a main class in Android java project where all functions are defined. Then I have 2 other classes that extend the main class and implement `Runnable`.

- main class: All main functions
- class 2: I use all main functions and have a static variable `X` which I modify in file 2.
- class 3: I use all main functions and have a static variable `Y` which I modify in file 3.

In the main class, I start 2 threads: one for Class2, and one for Class3.

When I try to call `Class2.X` from the main class, it is always `null` no matter what. I have tried `volatile`, `synchronized(thread)`, `getvalue()`, etc. but it is not working.

What should I do to read the values of `Class2.X` such that it is not null from the main class?

Here is the code:

```
Thread t = new Thread(new Functionss(mRgbImage));
t.start();
Thread t2 = new Thread(new Functionss_2(mRgbImage));
t2.start();

if(boolean_variable)
{
    try {
        Thread.sleep(30000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Bitmap final_added =addition(mRgbImage2, mRgbImage3);                 
    mImageView.setImageBitmap(final_added);
```

`mRgbImage2` and `mRgbImage3` are the `static volatile` variables.

In fact, I think it is not a problem of variables because when i use an image in the main class and modify it, and then execute `mImageView.setImageBitmap(initial_image)` i am still getting a black screen on my android phone.

I have noted the following in the logcat:

```
Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@40a34d28
```

If I remove the threads, I don't get this error.

Any help?

Comment: Can you show us some code?  Can you show your definitions for the fields in question?  You use the word "file" when I think you mean "class", right?

Comment: Yes every file defines a class.

Comment: Could `boolean_variable` be `false`?  Should that be a while loop or something.  `while (!boolean_variable) { sleep(1000); }` or something?

Comment: This may be an Android rendering error instead of a thread error.  Why don't you put a log message to verify that the image has changed.  I think your problem is that it is not re-rendering the image.

Comment: the boolean variable is true, i think it has to do with this warning but still can't figure out how

Comment: I think it is related to the threads because if i remove them and render an image it will appear just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that your threads are never executing the assignment statement or are assigning a different value or something.  Maybe putting some log messages or debugging your application and putting a break point at the assignment would help.

If you had something like:

```
public class MainClass {
    Class2 class2 = new Thread(new Class2());
    class2.start();
    class2.join();
    // Class2.value will == 10 here
}
```

and then:

```
public class Class2 implements Runnable {
    public static volatile int value;
    public void run() {
       ...
       this.value = 10;
       ...
    }
}
```

Then after the assignment happens in `Class2` then the `value` *will* have been updated.  This is obviously a simple example and I suspect the `Class2` thread has not actually finished in your code, but as long as the assignment has been reached then `value` *will* have been changed.  Again, log messages or debugger would help here.

It would be better to have something like the following pattern:

```
public class Class2 implements Runnable {
    private volatile int value;
    public void run() {
       ...
       this.value = 10;
       ...
    }
    public int getValue() {
        return this.value;
    }
}
```

So then `MainClass` can access the value from `Class2` and `Class3` without confusion.  Notice that you still need the `volatile` keyword there because the value is being get/set from different threads.

Hope something here helps.  If you edit your question with more details I may be able to help more.

Comment: Hey Gray, I posted the code and it might not be a problem of static variables, do u have any idea?

Comment: Sorry @Adroidist, I don't have an ideas.  I do not think that your original question is the problem.  Can you debug your code where the image is being displayed or add log message to see if it has been updated?

Answer (score 0):

I was using JJIL library and it turned out that

"
What steps will reproduce the problem?

1. Use RgbImageJ2se.toDisplay in multiiple threads simulatenous (different instances of RgbImageJ2se).

Due to the static reference to the Graphics object passed, there will be indeterminate results depending on which thread executes first.
"

Reference: http://code.google.com/p/jjil/issues/detail?id=27

I doubted it has to do with libraries because i rewrote the code with math functions instead and the output was right. it was waiting for both classes to finish and use their output to do further calcuations.

Hope this helps someone else stuck.